# Create email accounts via API and keep emails somewhere else (webmail)

Tags: email, email-server

we do have a email hosted in shared server where we can't create email accounts via API so I was Googling a solution but didn't find.

Want it so that emails are sent and received somewhere where there's maybe not that much space but the webmail client (Rainloop currently but maybe something else can be used) will be in our server where we have 8TB hard drive and all emails stored there.

Comment: so you wanna a mail server with a web-client which stores emails on your LAN-server? What prevents you from setup it on your server and expose it to internet? O365, for example [has API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for creating users, and it O365 supports hybrid environments. Good ol' Exchange is also an option with [its cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) for creating mailboxed

Comment: Yeah O365 cost £3 per user per month. Would like a solution that will cost per GB so we will keep big data amounts in our own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [ForwardEmail.net](https://forwardemail.net/en/pricing) for that. The free plan gives you unlimited domains and email forwarders but $3/month plan gives you also the API access and faster email delivery. There are of course more providers available but this one is the best value.

Another free option is [NameCheap.com](https://www.namecheap.com/) - all you need to do is to move your domain from your previous registrar to there. It is easy but just takes 5-7 days to move by them and then you need to point your name servers if you wish to manage your DNS somewhere else their advanced DNS manager is also very good so you can use them also for that. Their [API is super simple and well documented](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/) and as you can see from the [`domains.dns.setEmailForwarding` part of the API documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/domains-dns/set-email-forwarding/) you just get your `ApiKey` from your dashboard, add it to the URL with the domain name, email, and where to forward. Then you just GET call the URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).